# Start a SPD 2013 workflow from custom action and then redirect to home page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I have a situation here where i need to start a 2013 workflow on an item with the help of custom action, everything works fine though when I click on custom action a new tab gets open to start the workflow and then it gets redirected to the default view of the list. I need to redirect it to the home page of the site or any other specific page.

Note: As it's a 2013 workflow, it doesn't have an initiation form and I am looking for a solution which doesn't involve infopath.

Comment: I didn't understand the down vote. It's a genuine problem with no god solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to modify the URL of your custom action so that the source part of your URL goes where you want it to go.

If you copy your custom action's URL (in notepad or similar) you may see close to the end **&Source=** and it may be the address of your list. Change this Source URL to your home page or other page and see if that works.

Good luck!